# Creating default file for my application with images and text

Tags: java, image-processing, file-io

I have the following problem:

I need to save information that is currently on my application, and this information consists on images (.gif and .jpg) and text. I want to save everything in one single file, because saving only the image path for these images may cause an error if the user deletes any of the images. How can I save image and text into one single file using Java?

Comment: Are these images and text supplied with the app.?

Comment: Why do you want to save them in a single file? Why not put them in a folder in the user area.

Comment: you can write *.png,*.jpg,*.txt and zip them in 1 file..

Comment: You might want to google Java serialization.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The images and text are imported on a first usage of the app, and the user is able to edit text and images. I want to be able to save a current state of the app.

Comment: @mikea i don't want to save them in a separate folder to avoid the end user deleting any of the source files (imgs and text)

Comment: @KevinWorkman just googled it and i think this may work! thanks =)

Comment: @EugenHalca  If I had any votes left for the day, your comment would get one.  That approach has worked well for me in the past.  If you decide to make it an answer, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the files under one file

Code Example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try{

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MyFile.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry("spy.log");
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\spy.log");

        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();

        //remember close it
        zos.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```